# Need to receive 200 recommendation from flight search using java code for loop map function in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to receive 300 recommendation in one short using for loop using my code.

Currently I can receive one to 10 recommendation response. But when i deal with 200 to 500 recommendations it's so hard for me to edit my code from 1 to 500. Instead I try to implement the for loop in my code but it's fails.

Below is my code.

```
Map<String, String> recommendations5 = response.jsonPath().getMap("recommendation[5]");

System.out.print("\n\n");
System.out.print(recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
System.out.print("\n\n");
System.out.println("adultBaseFare=" + recommendations5.get("adultBaseFare"));
System.out.println("adultTaxFare=" + recommendations5.get("adultTaxFare"));
System.out.println("Deeplink=" + recommendations5.get("Deeplink"));
System.out.println("marketingAirlineCodes=" + recommendations5.get("marketingAirlineCodes"));
System.out.println("validatingAirlineName=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
System.out.println("totalBaseFare=" + recommendations5.get("totalBaseFare"));
System.out.println("totalFare=" + recommendations5.get("totalFare"));
System.out.println("validatingAirlineCode=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineCode"));
System.out.println("validatingAirlineName=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
```

Below is the my for loop logic but it fails.

My error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "i" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function

My for loop code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=jsonResponse.size();i++)
{
    Map<String, String> recommendations5 = response.jsonPath().getMap("recommendation[i]");
    System.out.print("\n\n");
    System.out.print(recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
    System.out.print("\n\n");
    System.out.println("adultBaseFare=" + recommendations5.get("adultBaseFare"));
    System.out.println("adultTaxFare=" + recommendations5.get("adultTaxFare"));
    System.out.println("Deeplink=" + recommendations5.get("Deeplink"));
    System.out.println("marketingAirlineCodes=" + recommendations5.get("marketingAirlineCodes"));
    System.out.println("validatingAirlineName=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
    System.out.println("totalBaseFare=" + recommendations5.get("totalBaseFare"));
    System.out.println("totalFare=" + recommendations5.get("totalFare"));
    System.out.println("validatingAirlineCode=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineCode"));
    System.out.println("validatingAirlineName=" + recommendations5.get("validatingAirlineName"));
}
```

Comment: `"recommendation[i]"` you probably want `"recommendation["+i+"]"`

Comment: After using the logics i am getting the error "class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List"

Comment: That must be at a different point in your code, which is not included in your post

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the String `i` will the actually `i` int value

```
Map<String, String> recommendations5 = response.jsonPath().getMap("recommendation[" + i + "]");
```

Comment: After using this logics i am getting below exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getMap(JsonPath.java:420)
 at qaflightsuppliers.QaFlightDXBLONResponseDebugValidation.main(QaFlightDXBLONResponseDebugValidation.java:88)

Comment: Looks like it is returning `class java.util.ArrayList`