# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

When working with REST Assured Java framework, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.LinkedHashMap and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getList(JsonPath.java:375)
    at qaflightsuppliers.QaFlightDXBLONResponseDebugValidation.main(QaFlightDXBLONResponseDebugValidation.java:94)
```

Below is my code. Please correct my code.

```java
List<String> jsonMapStringObjectResponse = response.jsonPath().get("recommendation");
        
for (int i = 0; i <= jsonMapStringObjectResponse.size(); i++)
{
    List<String> jsonMapObjectResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("recommendation[" + i + "]");
    System.out.print("ValidatingAirlineName="+jsonMapObjectResponse.add("validatingAirlineName"));
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `recommendation` is a list of objects, and not a list of lists you you seem to think. Please provide a reproducible example, which includes the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the attribute `recommendation` as a `List`, but in reality in the JSON response it's a `Map`.

So you have to change:

```
List<String> jsonMapObjectResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("recommendation[" + i + "]");
```

to

```
Map<String, String> jsonMapObjectResponse = response.jsonPath().getMap("recommendation[" + i + "]");
// example below
System.out.println(jsonMapObjectResponse.get("validatingAirlineName"));
```

Reverse engineered from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444010/need-to-receive-200-recommendation-from-flight-search-using-java-code-for-loop-m) your JSON probably looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "recommendation": {
      "validatingAirlineName": "...",
      "adultBaseFare": "...",
      "adultTaxFare": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "recommendation": {
      "validatingAirlineName": "...",
      "adultBaseFare": "...",
      "adultTaxFare": "..."
    }
  }
]
```

Tested and verified with this demo, which might be a good reading resource as well:

- https://devqa.io/parse-json-response-rest-assured/